# Android status bar gradient React Native

Tags: android, react-native, gradient, linear-gradients

I would like to put a gradient in android status bar [image]

in ios looks beautiful

[image]

I'm using linear gradient with angle

```
const insets = useSafeAreaInsets();

<StatusBar barStyle="light-content" backgroundColor={colors.navbarBackgroundStart} />

        <LinearGradient
            style={{ paddingTop: insets.top }}
            colors={[colors.navbarBackgroundStart, colors.navbarBackgroundEnd]}
            useAngle
            angle={150}
            angleCenter={{ x: 0.8, y: 0.8 }}
        >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to the `translucent` prop for android https://reactnative.dev/docs/statusbar#translucent-android

```js
const insets = useSafeAreaInsets();

<StatusBar barStyle="light-content" backgroundColor="transparent"  translucent />

<LinearGradient
   style={{ paddingTop: insets.top }}
   colors={[colors.navbarBackgroundStart, colors.navbarBackgroundEnd]}
   useAngle
   angle={150}
   angleCenter={{ x: 0.8, y: 0.8 }}
   >
```